# How can I use Keyboard navigation in ul, li

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

(First of all, I'm from South-Korea so might have some problem with grammar and ENG Skills. Sorry for that :( )

Hello, in the middle of upgrading our company site I want to fix previous function.
There are 2 Input text box, one for searching(box1) and one for show what clients choose(box2), with read-only.
When clients types searching keyword and press Enter-Key, function starts and create ul and li after ajax.

```
var newElem = document.createElement('ul');
newElem.setAttribute('id','userListUL');
newElem.setAttribute('style', 'margin-top:-2px; margin-left:1px; overflow:auto; cursor:pointer; position: absolute; background: #fff; border: solid 1px #999; width: 500px; height: 200px; z-index:99; ');
if(targetElement.id == 'projectInput'+idx){
    var url = '', data;
    if(targetElement.id == 'projectInput'+idx) {
        url = '***********************';
        data = {'projectNm':targetElement.value};
    } 
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'post',
        data:data,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(result){
            if(targetElement.id == 'projectInput'+idx) {
                if(result.dataSize==''){
                    fn_ListChk(targetElement.id, '', '');
                    return false;
                }else if(result.dataSize==1){
                    $.each(result.data,function(i,data){
                        var name = data.businessNm;
                        var id = data.businessNo;
                        fn_ListChk(targetElement.id, name, id);
                    });
                    return false;
                }else{
                    var htmlCode="";
                    $.each(result.data,function(i,data){
                        htmlCode+="<li class='addUserList'>["+data.performingYear+"Year] " +data.businessNm+"<input type='hidden' value='"+data.businessNo+"'></li>";
                    });
                    newElem.innerHTML=htmlCode;
                    targetElement.parentElement.insertBefore(newElem, targetElement.nextSibling);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
        error : function(xhr, status, error) {
            //alert("Please Check your Input Text");
        }
    });
    targetElement.value="";
}
```

Here's some part of js function where create UL and li.

```
    <td class="txtC">
        <input type="text" id="projectInput${vs.index }" class="pL5 size100per" onkeypress="fn_unregist(event,${vs.index})" onfocusout="fn_unregist(this)" placeholder="Write search keyword then press Enter-Key."><br>
        <input type="text" id="projectName${vs.index }" class="pL5 bg_gray size100per mTn1" readonly="readonly" value="${*****VO.projectNm}">
    </td>
```

I've used tab-index to focus li, and it worked but can't use Keyboard without use TAB key.
So clients only can use mouse to choose li. 
(Background color changed when hover, and mouse-out to show which li gonna choose.
When Click focused li, text of chosen li will show on projectName${vs.index})

I want to give focus to first li element after UL created,  use UP & DOWN key to move focus, Enter-Key to choose focused li.
I'm going to make function with Key.code, BTW want to know is there any other way to make it more comfortable , easier.
Thanks to all your support :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, show the codes you have tried for solution and where you do struggle at ;)